How to automate the deletion of data in Snowflake?
I am new to Snowflake and I was wondering if it is possible to automate the deletion of data?
For example: I have a table and after some time (3/6 months) of gathering data for analytics I want to delete the data existing there.
How can I automate this process?
Currently I have tried creating a stored procedure that does that and creating a task that will run this procedure at given intervals:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delte_old_data()

RETURNS STRING

EXECUTE AS CALLER

AS

$$

BEGIN

DELETE FROM MY_EVENTS_TABLE

WHERE CREATED_AT < DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

RETURN 'Old data deleted successfully!';

END;

$$;

and
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK delete_old_data_task

WAREHOUSE = MY_WAREHOUSE

SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 13 * * * UTC'

AS

CALL delete_old_data();

Is my approach wrong or do these 2 pieces of code need to be changed/ improved?

Can you please  tell how many rows are added in the table daily ?

For now I can't tell this is just a test to see if I can automate this process.
Do the number of rows have any effect on this?

The overall approach looks fine and is in the right direction and can be refined based on the further business requirement.
If there is a specific time based on which the data in the tables needs to be deleted, you may review the following article: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-delete-files-older-than-a-specific-date-in-a-Snowflake-stage
